# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException in java spring using constructor injection

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, constructor

Hello i am using constructor injection in my spring demo app when i run this program i got :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException exception

Anyone have solution where i am wong and whenever i run same program using setter injection it runs perfectly .

**Here is my EmployeeBean.java**

```
package cris;

public class Employee {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    public Employee() { }
    public Employee(int id,String name) {
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    void show() {
        System.out.println(id+" "+name);

    }
}
```

**Here is my Address Bean using setter injection**

```
package cris;

public class Address {
private String city,state,country;

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}


public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}


public String getState() {
    return state;
}


public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}


public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}


public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}


public String toString()
{
    return city+" "+state+" "+country;
}
}
```

**Here is my spring.xml** ie spring config file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">
<beans>
<bean id="a1" class="cris.Address">
<property name="city" value="Tikamgarh"></property>
<property name="state" value="Mp"></property>
<property name="country" value="India"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="e" class="cris.Employee">
<constructor-arg type="int" value="12"></constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg type="String" value="anil"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
</beans>
```

**And here is my Application Main Method**

```
package cris;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("cris/spring.xml");
    Employee emp = (Employee)context.getBean("e");
    emp.show();
}
}
```

kindly provide me suggestion where i am wrong so i will catch the exception thanks

The Exception:

```
Apr 03, 2017 4:16:16 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@27f8302d: startup date [Mon Apr 03 16:16:16 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Apr 03, 2017 4:16:16 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [cris/spring.xml]
Apr 03, 2017 4:16:16 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@17550481: defining beans [a1,e]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.inspectClass(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:112)
    at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1049)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at cris.Test.main(Test.java:8)
```

Comment: can you provide the exception for us please?

Comment: here is my exception link as it too long so i provide link sorry for inconvenient https://github.com/anildsvv14/Php-multiple-image-upload/blob/master/exception

Comment: Please edit your question with Exception message and code for `Address` class.

Comment: Try with `<constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="anil"></constructor-arg>` instead of only `String`.

Answer (score 0):

When filling POJO's, (for what I know) Spring calls the no-arg constructor by default. If you decide to write a cTor with parameters yourself, you will not get a default cTor generated and you'll have to add a no-arg cTor for spring yourself.

```
public Employee() { }
```

Comment: i have provide the default constructor also but no affect on the exception sir

Comment: No Answer will work for me actually every one has right code and right concept thanks for your valuable comment after long research i found the solution that i am using spring 3x with java 8 so the problem with that there are two solution to that  to install java 7 with spring 3x or use spring 4x with java 8

Comment: @AnilKumarSahu I sense some sarcasm, so pls tell me. What do you mean with your comment? Are you blaming me for not being able to help you any further? Then consider reading your question and what was actually the problem. No one could have figured that out. Besides, your next question I will not answer as you don't appreciate people trying to help you.

Comment: Sir Jeroen van Dijk-Jun i am not blemming you and not anyone in my comment i appreciate all the comment sir actually yesturday i tried it spring 4x libs and solve the problem i m sorry if you feel that i blame you. I just comment on line so that people having same problem can eassily understand the solution, my concern is to solve the problem not to blame anyone plz try to understand plz vote Question in positive so user can easilly find out the solution

Answer (score 0):

Add type to your constructor-arg

`<constructor-arg type="int" value="12" />`

and

`<constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="anil" />`

**EDIT**

or you can use indexes

`<constructor-arg index="0" value="12" />`

and

`<constructor-arg index="1" value="anil" />`

Comment: i have defined but no affect on exception sir

Comment: You will have another mistake here, this approach works for me.

Comment: Well - delete `<!DOCTYPE` line from  spring.xml

Comment: r u sure that code is run after removing the <!DOCTYPE line because i check the same it give me error

Answer (score 0):

Have spring.xml like this:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="a1" class="cris.Address">
<property name="city" value="Tikamgarh"></property>
<property name="state" value="Mp"></property>
<property name="country" value="India"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="e" class="cris.Employee">
<constructor-arg type="int" value="12"></constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg type="String" value="anil"></constructor-arg>
</bean>

</beans>
```

**EDIT**
My example:

spring.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="bean" class="Bean">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="Test"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="2"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Bean.java

```
public class Bean {

    private String test1;
    private int test2;

    public Bean(String test1, int test2) {
        this.test1 = test1;
        this.test2 = test2;
    }

    public String getTest1() {
        return test1;
    }

    public void setTest1(String test1) {
        this.test1 = test1;
    }

    public int getTest2() {
        return test2;
    }

    public void setTest2(int test2) {
        this.test2 = test2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bean{" +
                "test1='" + test1 + '\'' +
                ", test2=" + test2 +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Test.java

```
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");

        final Bean bean = (Bean) ctx.getBean("bean");

        System.out.println(bean.toString());
    }
}
```

prints:
`Bean{test1='Test', test2=2}`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and can't figure out why until I read each comment in current post and found out...

Using Spring 3.* and Java 11 that is a compatibility issue. When I downloaded the latest version (Spring 5.*) and set to the CLASSPATH. Then everything works.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can clearly point in the answer what range of Java versions are compatible with Spring 3.x.

Comment: And it is a time to point that Spring 3.x is reached its official EOL (end-of-life) on December 31st, 2016, according to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Versions