# IllegalArgumentException while pointing to an XML file in Spring

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I'm new to spring and I was trying constructor injection. I get an IllegalArgumentException in the first line of the main function. It does not have problems locating the xml file when I use a property tag inside the xml(setter injection) but here it is raising an exception.

**Triangle.java**

```
 package myPackage;

public class Triangle 
{
    private String type;


  public Triangle(String type) {

      this.type = type;
  }

  public String getType() {
      return type;
  }


  public void setType(String type) {
      this.type = type;
  }
  public void draw()
  {
      System.out.println(getType()+" Triangle Drawn");
  }
}
```

**DrawingApp.java**

```
package myPackage;


import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;


public class DrawingApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
    Triangle t = (Triangle) context.getBean("triangle");
    t.draw();


  }

}
```

**spring.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
    <bean id="triangle" class="myPackage.Triangle" >
    <constructor-arg  value="equilateral" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

These are the errors that I get.

```
Feb 05, 2018 1:41:14 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@2d8e6db6: startup date [Mon Feb 05 13:41:14 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
Feb 05, 2018 1:41:14 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring.xml]
Feb 05, 2018 1:41:14 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@17550481: defining beans [triangle]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.inspectClass(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:112)
    at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1049)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at myPackage.DrawingApp.main(DrawingApp.java:12)
```

Comment: what exception you get ?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Comment: Not sure it is required in this case, but try to add a `type="java.lang.String"` atrribute to your `constructor-arg` .

Comment: ... or `index="0"`

Comment: Please don't post errors / code / xml as screenshots, those become unreadable.

Comment: let me post it as plain text then.

Comment: Is it Maven project, or ...?

Comment: its java project

Comment: What are all your Spring dependencies ?

Comment: I've added them to the build path in form of a user library, where I have all the spring jars and apache commons jar

Comment: install java 7 with spring 3x or use spring 4x with java 8 as stated in this question's comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/43182849/5156075

Comment: Using spring 3x with java 6 solved my problem.